# How can I dynamically update a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout upon user action (i.e. sliding a UISlider)

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm working on a project that wants to achieve this feature: when the user slides a `UISlider`, the collectionView dynamically adds/reduces the number of columns like adding/removing columns in Google doc.

I tried to search for solution and some people suggested using `invalidateLayout()`. I added this method to the action of `UISlider` but the collectionView didn't update the layout.

This is my code for creating layout:

```
func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(numberOfColumns)), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: inset, leading: inset, bottom: inset, trailing: inset)
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(numberOfColumns)))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: numberOfColumns)
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}
```

The `numberOfColumns` will be updated based on user's action. I want it to also update the layout. I'm using Swift.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[add/remove column in Google doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bwUG.png)